# Downloading a file in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

`server.js`:

```
app.post('/api/download', async (req, res) => {
    res.json({status: 'ok'})
    return res.download('pera.txt', 'pera.txt')
})
```

`index.js`:

```
async function download()
{
    const result = await fetch('/api/download', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body:
        JSON.stringify({
            token,
        })
    }).then((res) => res.json())
}
```

And the request gets sent and I get this error in the terminal:

```yaml
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at SendStream.headersAlreadySent (/home/pera/Desktop/P2/node_modules/send/index.js:390:13)
    at SendStream.send (/home/pera/Desktop/P2/node_modules/send/index.js:617:10)
    at onstat (/home/pera/Desktop/P2/node_modules/send/index.js:729:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//res.json({status: 'ok'}) // remove this


//res.download(path [, filename] [, options] [, fn])


return res.download('pera.txt', function (err) {
    console.log(err)
})
```

At http server, we can send response once.

Comment: There is no error in the console anymore, but the file is not downloading.

Comment: the both of  `res.json` and `res.download` is function of send response, so, we cannot use two function

Comment: Yes i removed the res.json function, and it's still not downloading the file.

Comment: check the file path, there could be file 's absolute/relative path problem

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-res-download-function/

Comment: check the download function API

Comment: There is no current error message, it's just not downloading the file. I checked the file path and it's correct.

Comment: please try with `res.download('send/pera.txt')`

Comment: Tried the `res.download('send/pera.txt')`, and I got this error message `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/pera/Desktop/P2/send/pera.txt'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234917/discussion-between-mern-and-jedumisepalacinke).